# Automatically add new Page when table height exceed in iText

Tags: java, swing, itext

I am Working on a Project Where I have to Make a Sales Report in which I have a Page Title, Page Header, Bar Chart and Tables and its Grand Total etc. and Page Footer. I have used `ColumnText` to add Page Title, Page Header, Bar Chart and Tables and its Grand Total etc. and Page Footer in iText5 for absolute position of its component. I have a problem with `Table` in our database I have at most 15 rows but in Pdf Document it only shows 6 Rows. I want to add rest of these `Rows` in Next Page but it didn't appear, and I Also want to add Page Title and Page Footer in next Page of Pdf Document. After adding all those remaining rows at last Grand Total,Total Paid and Balance Box it will show.

Here is some source code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StackedBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

import com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel;
import com.itextpdf.awt.DefaultFontMapper;
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class SalesReport {

    private JFrame frmSalesReport;
    private static Connection con;
    private PreparedStatement PStat;
    private ResultSet res;
    private String query;
    private String Grand,totalpaid,paydue;
    private Double grand,grandtotal=0.0,Total_paid,tot_Paid=0.0,PayDue,Pay_Due=0.0;
    private JDateChooser ToDate,FromDate;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String\[\] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SalesReport window = new SalesReport();
                    window.frmSalesReport.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public SalesReport() {
        initialize();
        con=CompanyInfo.Database();
    }

    public void GenerateReport()
    {
        try
        {
            Document document=new Document();       
            PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("SalesReport.pdf"));       
            document.open();

            PdfContentByte canvas=writer.getDirectContent();

            Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(1,715,600,841);//left,bottom,right,top
            rect.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
            rect.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(31,155,118));
            rect.setBorderWidth(2);
            rect.setBorderColor(new BaseColor(31,155,118));
            canvas.rectangle(rect);

            String imagename="C:/Users/Mdazaz/workspace/InventorySystem/Images/index3.jpg";
            Image img=Image.getInstance(imagename);
            img.scaleToFit(100, 100);
            img.setAbsolutePosition(80, 730);
            canvas.addImage(img);


            String Title="ABC Pvt. Ltd.";
            Paragraph paraTitle=new Paragraph(Title,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,14,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE));
            paraTitle.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            String Address="356/3 Malviaya Nagar Near Khatushiyam Mandir Indore";
            Paragraph paraAddress=new Paragraph(Address,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,14,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE));            
            paraAddress.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            String Contact="Contact No.=7030456328";
            Paragraph paraContact=new Paragraph(Contact,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,14,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE));            
            paraContact.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            String Email="Email ID: mohammadazaz966@gmail.com";
            Paragraph paraEmail=new Paragraph(Email,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,14,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE));            
            paraEmail.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            ColumnText column=new ColumnText(canvas);
            column.setSimpleColumn(200,840,454,720);
            column.addElement(paraTitle);
            column.addElement(paraAddress);
            column.addElement(paraContact);
            column.addElement(paraEmail);
            column.go();

            Date date=new Date();
            Paragraph paradate=new Paragraph(date.toString(),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,14,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK));           
            paradate.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            Rectangle footer=new Rectangle(1,1,594,50);//left,bottom,right,top
            footer.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
            footer.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(31,155,118));
            footer.setBorderWidth(2);
            footer.setBorderColor(new BaseColor(31,155,118));
            canvas.rectangle(footer);

            String page="Page Number: "+String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber());
            Paragraph parapage=new Paragraph(page,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,14,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE));          
            parapage.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            ColumnText columnFooter=new ColumnText(canvas);
            columnFooter.setSimpleColumn(footer);
            columnFooter.addElement(parapage);
            columnFooter.go();

            DateFormat year=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
            String fromyear=year.format(FromDate.getDate());
            String toyear=year.format(ToDate.getDate());

            int fyear=Integer.parseInt(fromyear);
            int tyear=Integer.parseInt(toyear);

            Date date1=FromDate.getDate();
            Date date2=ToDate.getDate();
            String fromDate=DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date1);//((JTextField)FromDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
            String toDate=DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date2);//((JTextField)FromDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();

            int serialNo=1;

            PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(7);
            table.setSplitLate(false);
            PdfPCell Data=new PdfPCell();
            table.setWidthPercentage(110);

            String serialno="Serial No";
            Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(serialno,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,10,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE)));
            Data.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
            Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
            Data.setBorderWidth(1);
            table.addCell(Data);

            String Invoice="Invoice No";
            Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Invoice,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,10,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE)));
            Data.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
            Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
            Data.setBorderWidth(1);
            table.addCell(Data);

            String InvoiceDate="Invoice Date";
            Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(InvoiceDate,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,10,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE)));
            Data.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
            Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
            Data.setBorderWidth(1);
            table.addCell(Data);

            String Cname="Customer Name";
            Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Cname,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,10,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE)));
            Data.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
            Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
            Data.setBorderWidth(1);
            table.addCell(Data);

            String GrandTotal="Grand Total";
            Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(GrandTotal,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,10,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE)));
            Data.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
            Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
            Data.setBorderWidth(1);
            table.addCell(Data);


            String TotalPaid="Total Paid";
            Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(TotalPaid,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,10,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE)));
            Data.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
            Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
            Data.setBorderWidth(1);
            table.addCell(Data);

            String Balance="Balance";
            Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Balance,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,10,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE)));
            Data.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
            Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
            Data.setBorderWidth(1);
            table.addCell(Data);

            String CGtot="   Grand Total :";
            Paragraph paraCGtot=new Paragraph(CGtot,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,12,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK));            
            paraCGtot.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

            String CTotpaid="   Total Paid :";
            Paragraph paraCTotpaid=new Paragraph(CTotpaid,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,12,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK));          
            paraCTotpaid.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

            String Cbalance="   Balance :";
            Paragraph paraCbalance=new Paragraph(Cbalance,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,12,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK));          
            paraCbalance.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

            Rectangle RecColFoot2=new Rectangle(570,80,350,148);//left,bottom,right,top
            RecColFoot2.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
            RecColFoot2.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
            RecColFoot2.setBorderWidth(2);
            RecColFoot2.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
            canvas.rectangle(RecColFoot2);

            ColumnText columnFoot2=new ColumnText(canvas);
            columnFoot2.setSimpleColumn(RecColFoot2);
            columnFoot2.addElement(paraCGtot);
            columnFoot2.addElement(paraCTotpaid);
            columnFoot2.addElement(paraCbalance);
            columnFoot2.go();

            Rectangle RecColFoot3=new Rectangle(450,83,567,145);//left,bottom,right,top
            RecColFoot3.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
            RecColFoot3.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
            RecColFoot3.setBorderWidth(2);
            RecColFoot3.setBorderColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
            canvas.rectangle(RecColFoot3);

            ColumnText columnDatafOOT=new ColumnText(canvas);
            columnDatafOOT.setSimpleColumn(RecColFoot3);

            DefaultCategoryDataset myBardataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();


            query="Select * from BillingCustomer where In_Date>='"+fromDate+"' OR In_Date<='"+toDate+"'";
            PStat=con.prepareStatement(query);
            res=PStat.executeQuery();
            while(res.next())
            {
                Grand=res.getString("G_Tot");
                grand=Double.parseDouble(Grand);
                grandtotal=grandtotal+grand;

                totalpaid=res.getString("Tot_Pay");
                Total_paid=Double.parseDouble(totalpaid);
                tot_Paid=tot_Paid+Total_paid;

                paydue=res.getString("Pay_Due");
                PayDue=Double.parseDouble(paydue);
                Pay_Due=Pay_Due+PayDue;

                String serialNum=Integer.toString(serialNo);
                Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(serialNum,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ITALIC,11,Font.ITALIC,BaseColor.BLACK)));
                Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
                Data.setBorderWidth(1);
                Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(Data);
                serialNo++;

                String InvoiceNo=res.getString("In_Code");
                Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(InvoiceNo,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ITALIC,11,Font.ITALIC,BaseColor.BLACK)));
                Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
                Data.setBorderWidth(1);
                Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(Data);

                String Invoicedate=res.getString("In_Date");
                Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Invoicedate,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ITALIC,11,Font.ITALIC,BaseColor.BLACK)));
                Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
                Data.setBorderWidth(1);
                Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(Data);

                String CName=res.getString("C_Name");
                Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(CName,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ITALIC,11,Font.ITALIC,BaseColor.BLACK)));
                Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
                Data.setBorderWidth(1);
                Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(Data);

                Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Grand,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ITALIC,11,Font.ITALIC,BaseColor.BLACK)));
                Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
                Data.setBorderWidth(1);
                Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(Data);

                Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(totalpaid,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ITALIC,11,Font.ITALIC,BaseColor.BLACK)));
                Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
                Data.setBorderWidth(1);
                Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(Data);

                String CPayDue=res.getString("Pay_Due");
                Data=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(CPayDue,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ITALIC,11,Font.ITALIC,BaseColor.BLACK)));
                Data.setFixedHeight(30f);
                Data.setBorderWidth(1);
                Data.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                Data.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(Data);            

            }
            myBardataset.setValue(new Double(grandtotal), "Total Sales", Integer.toString(fyear));

            Paragraph paraCG_Tot=new Paragraph(Double.toString(grandtotal),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,12,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK));         
            paraCG_Tot.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            columnDatafOOT.addElement(paraCG_Tot);
            columnDatafOOT.go();

            Paragraph paraCTot_Pay=new Paragraph(Double.toString(tot_Paid),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,12,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK));         
            paraCTot_Pay.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            columnDatafOOT.addElement(paraCTot_Pay);
            columnDatafOOT.go();

            Paragraph paraCPay_Due=new Paragraph(Double.toString(Pay_Due),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,12,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK));          
            paraCPay_Due.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            columnDatafOOT.addElement(paraCPay_Due);
            columnDatafOOT.go();

            ColumnText columnTable=new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
            columnTable.setSimpleColumn(50,380,544,170);
            columnTable.addElement(table);
            columnTable.go();

            JFreeChart barchart=ChartFactory.createBarChart("Total Sales/Year", "Years", "Total Sales", myBardataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,false,true,false);
            CategoryPlot plot=barchart.getCategoryPlot();
            plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.black);
            StackedBarRenderer renderer=new StackedBarRenderer(false);
            renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
            renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
            renderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,18));
            barchart.getCategoryPlot().setRenderer(renderer);
            renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.decode("#84002E"));
            renderer.setBaseItemLabelPaint(Color.white);

            Rectangle bar=new Rectangle(60,650,330,410);//left,bottom,right,top
            bar.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
            bar.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
            bar.setBorderWidth(2);
            bar.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
            canvas.rectangle(bar);

            Rectangle fromdate=new Rectangle(50,700,550,670);//left,bottom,right,top
            fromdate.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
            fromdate.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(31,155,118));
            fromdate.setBorderWidth(2);
            fromdate.setBorderColor(new BaseColor(31,155,118));
            canvas.rectangle(fromdate);

            String Fromdate="From : "+fromDate+"         To : "+toDate+"         "+paradate;
            Paragraph parafromdate=new Paragraph(Fromdate,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,14,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE));          
            parafromdate.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            ColumnText columnfromdate=new ColumnText(canvas);
            columnfromdate.setSimpleColumn(fromdate);
            columnfromdate.addElement(parafromdate);
            columnfromdate.go();

            Rectangle bartitle=new Rectangle(570,620,374,650);//left,bottom,right,top
            bartitle.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
            bartitle.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(31,155,118));
            bartitle.setBorderWidth(2);
            bartitle.setBorderColor(new BaseColor(31,155,118));
            canvas.rectangle(bartitle);

            String BarChartTitle="                Sales Report";
            Paragraph paraBar=new Paragraph(BarChartTitle,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,14,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.WHITE));          
            paraBar.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            ColumnText columnDate=new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
            columnDate.setSimpleColumn(bartitle);
            columnDate.setText(paraBar);
            columnDate.go();

            int width=450;
            int height=400;

            File Barchart=new File("BarChart.png");
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(Barchart, barchart, width, height);

            String imageBar="BarChart.png";
            Image imgbar=Image.getInstance(imageBar);
            imgbar.scaleToFit(400, 200);
            imgbar.setAbsolutePosition(80, 430);
            canvas.addImage(imgbar);

            document.close();
            res.close();
            PStat.close();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Report Generated");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new WebLookAndFeel());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        frmSalesReport = new JFrame();
        frmSalesReport.setTitle("Sales Report");
        frmSalesReport.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 358);
        frmSalesReport.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmSalesReport.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
        panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 116, 90));
        panel.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 49);
        frmSalesReport.getContentPane().add(panel);

        JLabel lblSalesReport = new JLabel("Sales Report");
        lblSalesReport.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblSalesReport.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblSalesReport.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        lblSalesReport.setBounds(10, 15, 394, 20);
        panel.add(lblSalesReport);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Search By Invoice Date", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, Color.BLACK));
        panel_1.setBounds(10, 71, 414, 156);
        frmSalesReport.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("From :");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 31, 46, 14);
        panel_1.add(lblNewLabel);

        FromDate = new JDateChooser();
        FromDate.setBounds(10, 56, 161, 25);
        panel_1.add(FromDate);

        JLabel lblTo = new JLabel("To :");
        lblTo.setBounds(243, 31, 46, 14);
        panel_1.add(lblTo);

        ToDate = new JDateChooser();
        ToDate.setBounds(243, 56, 161, 25);
        panel_1.add(ToDate);

        JButton ViewReport1 = new JButton("View Report 1");
        ViewReport1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                GenerateReport();
            }
        });
        ViewReport1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Mdazaz\\workspace\\InventorySystem\\Images\\Bullish_48px.png"));
        ViewReport1.setBounds(30, 105, 126, 32);
        panel_1.add(ViewReport1);

        JButton ViewReport2 = new JButton("View Report 2");
        ViewReport2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Mdazaz\\workspace\\InventorySystem\\Images\\Pie Chart_40px.png"));
        ViewReport2.setBounds(259, 105, 126, 32);
        panel_1.add(ViewReport2);

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
        panel_2.setBounds(10, 232, 414, 70);
        frmSalesReport.getContentPane().add(panel_2);
        panel_2.setLayout(null);

        JButton Reset = new JButton("Reset");
        Reset.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Mdazaz\\workspace\\InventorySystem\\Images\\Refresh_40px.png"));
        Reset.setBounds(62, 18, 126, 32);
        panel_2.add(Reset);

        JButton Close = new JButton("Close");
        Close.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Mdazaz\\workspace\\InventorySystem\\Images\\Close Window_48px.png"));
        Close.setBounds(238, 18, 126, 32);
        panel_2.add(Close);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're question is inconsistent. The subject says you want a new page to be created automatically (you want iText to take control to create a layout). The code in the body of your question says you don't want a new page to be created (you take control over the layout). You can't have both. If you want the content that remains available in the `ColumnText` to be *consumed*, you have to trigger `document.newPage()` yourself, create a new rectangle for the column, and as long as `ColumnText.hasMoreText(columnTable.go());`

Comment: How to do it give some piece of source code.

Comment: See my previous comment. It contains the pieces of code you need. Just add those snippets.

Comment: It is not working it remain same no any changes

Comment: If it's not working, then you're doing it wrong. Maybe you didn't read the documentation: [How to fit a String inside a rectangle?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-fit-string-inside-rectangle) [How to divide a page in N parts so we can fill each with a different source?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-divide-page-n-parts-so-we-can-fill-each-different-source) [How can I add titles of chapters in ColumnText?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/de/node/1903)

Answer (score 0):

This is the Answer of my Question:

```
       `ColumnText columnTable=new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        columnTable.setSimpleColumn(50,170,544,380);
        columnTable.addElement(table);
        int status=columnTable.go();
        while(columnTable.hasMoreText(status))
        {
            Footer();//before leaving the page add footer in current page
            document.newPage();//create a new page
            Header();//adding header to new page
            putDate();//adding date to new page
            columnTable.setSimpleColumn(50,650,544,150);// adding position of table in new page
            status=columnTable.go();//start to paste all table data
            Footer();// before leaving the new page add footer on current page / new page
        }`
```